Microsoft Graph API, Corrupted files while uploading to sharepoint
Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/${driveID}/root:/${folder}/${filename}:/content
Content-Type: 'text/plain'
Request Body:
Since Im using SheetJs to create excel programatically, this is what im putting in my request body:
var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx',  type: 'binary'});
wbout is used for the request body since XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx',  type: 'binary'}) will generate the excel file in binary.
I successfully uploaded to sharepoint but can't open because file is corrupted.
is there any solution to this?
Thanks.
I have tried downloading the file using this:
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), fileName) 
function s2ab(s) {  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length); //convert s to arrayBuffer var view = new Uint8Array(buf);  //create uint8array as viewer for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF; //convert to octet return buf;     }
and is working fine, i can download and open the excel file.

The issue with the corrupted file may be due to the content type being set to 'text/plain'. To upload an Excel file, you should set the content type to 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'. You can try changing the content type and see if it resolves the issue.
